# How can I enumerate all the controls on a view?

Tags: quickbase

I would like to get ALL the ui components in a quickbase view. Is there a api that enumerates them, returns IDs, names, etc?

Answer (score 0):

There is [API_GetSchema](https://help.quickbase.com/api-guide/index.html#getschema.html%3FTocPath%3DQuick%2520Base%2520API%2520Call%2520Reference%7C_____45) which returns field information, 
queries and variables of a table. That would give you the field id, label (name), type, est. It's not a view but an API call